# Image showing just sometimes

Tags: java, image, drawing

I have a really annoying problem:

I want to draw an image, i have loaded before (it seems to be loaded correctly). But now something really strange happens: **sometimes**, the image appears, and **sometimes** it doesn´t!
But when I minimize the whole frame and maximize it again, the image is **always** there!
Of course i am repainting the whole thing when i have drawn the image, but as I said, nothing happens, the image does not (always) show.

What am I doing wrong?

Ok, the problem code:

```
      //this is the method I load my image with
   private BufferedImage loadImage(String name) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new File(name));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


    //this is the paint method of my JPanel
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
```

Comment: Please specify what language you're using and post a relevant code snippet.

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/),

Answer (score 0):

how do you draw the image?

What is your environment ? WPF,Winform...

Most common issue is that you have to use the paint event. because once drawn, your shapes, images... are los as soon as a new paint process starts

Comment: 1. Thanks for that quick answer!
2. I am drawing the image with the paint method of my JPanel:'g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);'
and my environment: I am using mac

Comment: ok, i have temporarily solved the problem: 


I repaint my frame, which contains all the panels, also the problem-panel. for the moment it works, but i dont think thats a good solution.
Now I also know, that my problem is that the paint method isnt called, although i call 'repaint()' and 'setVisible(true)'. So as @Boas Enkler said, it must have to do sth. with the paint events.
So if anybody knows what to do, please help me.

Many Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to help you but i only do now the .net world in this area. Is there something like a paint event which passes you some paint eventargs in it ? Normally you should use the eventargs that are pased in.

Comment: in Java you normally work with repaint(), a parents repaint() repaints automatically the children. but in my case I call repaint() (I have tried it many times in different places), even the parents repaint, but the repaints seem to be ignored unless I call the very parents repaint().

Comment: is repaint the trigger, or eventhandling method ? For Example In .net a Invalidate triggets all paint events of the childs

Comment: its the trigger method, it calls the paint(Graphics g) method, which should not be called directly. but it (paint(), the handler) can be overridden, thats what you do to oaint sth except of rhe empty panel

Comment: and the problem is: I can trigger as much as I want, sometimes Java decides just to ignore the events (dont ask me why)